# Cannot find module './src/Commands/Tools/ping.js'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Every time I try to run my discord bot I get this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module './src/Commands/Tools/ping.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/011935/Programming/JS/Bots/Command Bot v3/src/Functions/Handlers/commandHandler.js
- /Users/011935/Programming/JS/Bots/Command Bot v3/src/bot.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:893:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at client.handleCommands (/Users/011935/Programming/JS/Bots/Command Bot v3/src/Functions/Handlers/commandHandler.js:15:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/011935/Programming/JS/Bots/Command Bot v3/src/bot.js:19:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/011935/Programming/JS/Bots/Command Bot v3/src/Functions/Handlers/commandHandler.js',
    '/Users/011935/Programming/JS/Bots/Command Bot v3/src/bot.js'
  ]
}
```

Here are my bot.js, commandHandler.js, and ping.js files and my file structure

bot.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { token } = process.env;
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
client.commands = new Collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/Functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./src/Functions/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles)
    require(`./Functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

client.handleCommands();
client.handleEvents();

client.login(token);
```

commandHandler.js

```
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("node:path");

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleCommands = async () => {
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/Commands`);
    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
      const commandFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`src/Commands/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

      const { commands, commandArray } = client;
      for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`src/Commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        commandArray.push(command, command.data.toJSON());
        console.log(`Command: ${command.data.name} has been registered`);
      }
    }

    const clientId = "1070133880671174697";
    const guildId = "1070126560004276305";
    const rest = new REST({ version: "9" }).setToken(process.env.token);

    try {
      console.log("Started refreshing commands.");

      await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId, guildId), {
        body: client.commandArray,
      });

      console.log("Successfully refreshed commands.");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
};
```

ping.js

```
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Returns my ping"),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    console.log("pinged");
  },
};
```

File Structure

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSe0h.png)

I've tried editing it myself, checking I've written the right code in the tutorial, and extensive googling, but nothing works, and for people who have had the same problem theirs just 'magically' fixed.

Edit 1 - I have tried ../../src as @rebe100x suggested but when I did path.basename it gave me this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'Tools'
```

Edit 2 - I used 'src/Commands/${folder} but now it gives me the same error as before

Comment: I think the error comes from the relative path to ping.js in commandHandler.js at line 14 (require(`./src/Commands/${folder}/${file}`)  you call ping.js from a file which is not at the root of your directory. You should use ../../src but it would be better to use : https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Answer (score 0):

On commandHandler.js line 15

```js
const command = require(`./src/Commands/${folder}/${file}`);
```

The file directory is wrong. From your structure, commandHandler.js is in `Function > Handlers > commandHandler.js`.

Simply change the directory to `../../src/Commands/${folder}/${file}` and it should fix the path problem